# Get state variable from child component using React 16.8^ coding style

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, state-management

This question has already been asked but i cannot find an answer using hooks.

I need to read a state variable in the page that calls a component.

MyPage.js

```
import React from "react"
import MyComponent from "../components/MyComponent"

export default function MyPage() {
  console.log("Read stateVariable value here " + stateVariable) // produce error
  return (
      <MyComponent />
  )
}
```

MyComponent.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import ExternalModule from "ExternalModule"

export default function MyComponent() {

const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(0))

 return (
    <div
      onClick={setStateVariable(stateVariable + 1)}
    >CLICK HERE
      <ExternalModule
        stateVariable={stateVariable}
      />
    </div>
  )
```

How to console.log `stateVariable` in MyPage?

Comment: Are you asking about [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)?

Comment: Might be, as specified in the title I'm looking for a React-with-hooks explanation, as I'm not familiar with Class / Constructor / this.state, which is used in the official documentation (your link). AFAIK lifting state up is not the usual way of handling state management with react hooks, but i might be wrong too

Comment: Lifting state is a design pattern, react hooks are an implementation detail. They have nothing to do with each other. Move `const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(0);` to `MyPage` and pass `stateVariable` and `setStateVariable` as props to `MyComponent` to render and attach as `onClick` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple components that need to access a piece of state, you want that state to be owned by the highest-up component in the tree and passed down to the rest.

Move the `useState` call up to `MyPage` and pass both `stateVariable` and `setStateVariable` down to `MyComponent` as props.

```
export default function MyPage() {

    const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(0)

    console.log("Read stateVariable value here " + stateVariable)

    return (
        <MyComponent 
            stateVariable={stateVariable} 
            setStateVariable={setStateVariable} 
        />
    )
}

export default function MyComponent({ stateVariable, setStateVariable]) {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={setStateVariable(stateVariable + 1)}
        >CLICK HERE
            <ExternalModule
                stateVariable={stateVariable}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```